# How to create stored procedure for insert data from one table to other table by passing parameter

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

There are two tables 
1.FinalTable(f1,f2,f3,f4)
2.DemoTable_1(d1,d2,d3,d4)

I want to insert data from DemoTable_1 to FinalTable using the following SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO `FinalTable`
(`f1`,`f2`,`f3`,`f4`)
 (SELECT `d1`,`d2`,`d3`,`d4`
 FROM DemoTable_1);
```

So I want to create the procedure by passing DemoTable_1 as a parameter for the procedure.
So I can change the source table as DemoTable_2, DemoTable_3, DemoTable_4 and so on..

I am using SQLyog community

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FinalTable_insert(IN source_table VARCHAR(40))
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO `FinalTable`
(`f1`,`f2`,`f3`,`f4`)
 (SELECT `d1`,`d2`,`d3`,`d4`
 FROM source_table);
 END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL FinalTable_insert('DemoTable_1');
```

> Error Code: 1146
>       Table 'source_table' doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

The input variables doesn't evaluate as table names, you must build a query in a string and execute that using prepared statement:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS FinalTable_insert //
CREATE PROCEDURE FinalTable_insert(IN source_table VARCHAR(40))
 BEGIN

    SET @sql = CONCAT("INSERT INTO `FinalTable`
            (`f1`,`f2`,`f3`,`f4`)
            SELECT `d1`,`d2`,`d3`,`d4`
            FROM `",source_table,"`");

    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1; 

 END //
DELIMITER ;
```